# TightVNC suddenly stops taking input

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu-20.04, tightvnc

I have a TightVNC server running on an Ubuntu computer and am connecting to it through an SSH tunnel from a Windows 10 computer. It usually works completely fine until seemingly at random it just stops taking input. I can still see the mouse move, but can't click or type.  I then have to close the VNC viewer, kill the server through the SSH shell, restart it, then reconnect and it works again. I don't really know what could cause this.

Edit:
Here is the tutorial I was following:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-20-04

and I changed the xstartup to:

```
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources

unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

startxfce4 &
```

because the screen was completely grey.

Comment: NOT AN ANSWER BUT.. When I quit using VNC and started using X11 forwarding, problems like this quit happening.  X11 forwarding is built into your Ubuntu box already and the performance is WAY WAY better.  On the downside, you won't get the entire desktop.. only individual apps because Windows will be acting as your window manager.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't quite found a perfect solution yet but I figured out it was because the computer was going to sleep. It doesn't go to the lock screen and just locks up. Telling it to not sleep ever fixed the issue for the most part, along with switching to x11vnc.